# Radlibrary for Facebook Ads as_tibble function not working "Column `percentage` not found in `.data`"

Tags: r, facebook

I'm using the Radlibrary package in R and have used it several times. Now I want to update my data on Facebook Ads but when running the `as_tibble` function to convert the data I have in class `paginated_adlib_data_response` I'm being met with the error message: `` Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `percentage`. x Column `percentage` not found in `.data` ``

Last time I used the API and Radlibrary package was back in May. I don't know if it's the dplyr package that has changed and now producing the problem or if Facebook has changed in it's dataformat. The problem only arises for demographic and regional data - the 'ad' part of the data still works fine with the `as_tibble`  function.

Does anyone know the answer to this or perhaps know another way of converting the "paginated_adlib_data_response" into a data.frame format or something similar?

My code looks like this:

````
query_dem <- adlib_build_query(ad_reached_countries = 'DK', 
                               ad_active_status = 'ALL', 
                               search_page_ids = ID_media$page_id,
                               fields = "demographic_data")

result_dem <- adlib_get_paginated(query_dem, max_gets = 100)

tibble_dem <- as_tibble(result_dem, type = "demographic") # This is where the error is produced``` 

Best,
Mads
````

Comment: Have you updated the package recently? It looks like that problem was addressed in a [pull request](https://github.com/facebookresearch/Radlibrary/pull/89) 5 days ago. Reinstall the package with `devtools::install_github("facebookresearch/Radlibrary")`. It's a good idea to check the github page for a package that you are having troubles with to see if the error has already been reported and corrected.

Comment: Arh, you're right! Thank you so much for the advice and for taking your time to help me out. Much appreciated.